# While creating a to-do-list in React JS. I am getting - ( Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`DisplayTasks`) )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**This is my Textinserter.js**

*In this JS file I have a text field to enter the task and a button to add that task to a tasks array*

```
// Import React and useState from the 'react' library
import React, { useState } from "react";

// Create a functional component named Textinserter
export default function Textinserter({ tasks, setTasks }) {
  // Initialize state variables using useState hook: tasks and tasksInput
  const [tasksInput, setTasksInput] = useState("");

  // Function to handle changes in the input field
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    // Update tasksInput state with the value entered in the input field
    setTasksInput(e.target.value);
  };

  // Function to add a task to the tasks list
  const addTask = () => {
    // Check if the trimmed input is not an empty string
    if (tasksInput.trim() !== "") {
      // Create a new task object with an ID and name
      const newTask = { id: tasks.length + 1, name: tasksInput };

      // Update tasks state using the functional form of setTasks
      setTasks((prevTasks) => [...prevTasks, newTask]);

      // Clear the tasksInput state after adding the task
      setTasksInput("");
    }
  };

  // Return JSX for the component
  return (
    <>
      <div className="mb-3">
        {/* Input field and label */}
        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">
          Enter The Task
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="exampleInputEmail1"
          aria-describedby="emailHelp"
          onChange={handleOnChange} // Handle input changes with handleOnChange function
          value={tasksInput}
        />
        {/* Button to add a task */}
        <div className="conatiner text-center">
          <button className="btn btn-danger my-3" onClick={addTask}>
            Add Task
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**This is the Displaytasks.js**

*This code displays the tasks inside the Tasks array and also has a delete Button which should delete a particular task. But I am getting a warning -*

```
import React from "react";

// Component to display tasks
export default function DisplayTasks({ tasks, onDelete }) {
  const deleteTask = (taskId) => {
    // Filter out the task with the matching ID and update tasks array
    const updatedTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== taskId);
    onDelete(updatedTasks);
  };

  // Styling for the main container
  const myStyle = {
    backgroundColor: "#0D6EFD",
    padding: "15px",
    borderRadius: "10px",
  };

  return (
    <div
      // Conditional styling based on the tasks length
      style={
        tasks.length === 0 ? { ...myStyle, visibility: "hidden" } : myStyle
      }
    >
      {/* Heading for the tasks */}
      <h1 className="text-center text-light mb-4">Today's Tasks</h1>

      {tasks && tasks.length > 0 ? ( // Check if tasks exist and not empty
        <ul className="list-group" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          {tasks.map((task) => (
            <div
              key={task.id}
              className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
            >
              {/* Container for each task */}
              <span
                className="d-inline-block w-100 overflow-hidden m-2"
                style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }} // Styling for each task container
              >
                {/* List item for the task */}
                <li className="list-group-item" aria-current="true">
                  {task.name}
                </li>
              </span>
              {/* Button to delete the task */}
              <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={deleteTask(task.id)}>
                Delete
              </button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : (
        // Display if tasks array is empty or undefined
        <p>No tasks available</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

> App.js:10 Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`DisplayTasks`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `DisplayTasks`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
> at DisplayTasks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:122:3)
> at div
> at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33:76)

**This is my App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import Textinserter from "./Components/Textinserter";
import DisplayTasks from "./Components/DisplayTasks";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]); // Define tasks and setTasks in App component

  const handleTaskDeletion = (updatedTasks) => {
    setTasks(updatedTasks);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <Textinserter tasks={tasks} setTasks={setTasks} />
      <DisplayTasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={handleTaskDeletion} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried to run the code myself, but it seems like the problem is in your `DisplayTasks` component.

below is your original code..

```
import React from "react";

// Component to display tasks
export default function DisplayTasks({ tasks, onDelete }) {
  const deleteTask = (taskId) => {
    // Filter out the task with the matching ID and update tasks array
    const updatedTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== taskId);
    onDelete(updatedTasks);
  };

  return (
    // ...
      <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={deleteTask(task.id)}>
        Delete
      </button>
    // ...
  );
}
```

your `deleteTask` function updates the state of `App` component, and it is called during render, since you have put `deleteTask(task.id)` into button's onClick prop.

onClick should be a function that should be ran when it is clicked. instead, you are calling a deleteTask function and it's return (which is void) is given as a prop.

you just have to change it to a anonymous function, like below

```
import React from "react";

// Component to display tasks
export default function DisplayTasks({ tasks, onDelete }) {
  const deleteTask = (taskId) => {
    // Filter out the task with the matching ID and update tasks array
    const updatedTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== taskId);
    onDelete(updatedTasks);
  };

  return (
    // ...
      <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteTask(task.id)}>
        Delete
      </button>
    // ...
  );
}
```

or, maybe you could change your `deleteTask` function to return a function and use it.

```
import React from "react";

// Component to display tasks
export default function DisplayTasks({ tasks, onDelete }) {
  const deleteTask = (taskId) => () => {
    // Filter out the task with the matching ID and update tasks array
    const updatedTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== taskId);
    onDelete(updatedTasks);
  };

  return (
    // ...
      <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={deleteTask(task.id)}>
        Delete
      </button>
    // ...
  );
}
```